# PHP: blog - how to add the date to a comment

Tags: php, date, time, blogs

I am building a simple php script to manage a blog, but i am stack..

Right now is possible to insert in a form the: name,  mail, content.
And the comment will be display properly.

I would like to attach to every comment the exact date and time of the comment.

I pass all the afternoon reading about `date()` `time()` and `timestamp()` but i don't get anything out of it.

Someone can help me to add the date and time to the comments, in a simple way?

Thank you!!

the query right now is just this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO posts (name, mail, content) VALUES 
               ('$this->name', '$this->mail', '$this->content')";
```

Comment: please post the lines of code that do the db insert line to make answering this more relevant to your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `DATETIME` column to your table. Insert `date('Y-m-d H:i:s)` into that column when you're inserting the comment. Then you can parse that time (if you wish to display it in any other way than the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format. There's a couple of ways you can do this, some suggestions are with the strtotime and date or strftime functions or the DateTime class.

**Update**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO posts (name, mail, content, datetime) VALUES ('$this->name', '$this->mail', '$this->content', " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s) . ")";
```

Comment: Thanks!
Right now i have done this:
- Add a field to the table called 'datetime' type: date.
-  $this->datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
and the query:
            $query = "INSERT INTO posts (name, mail, content, datetime) VALUES 
                   ('$this->name', '$this->mail', '$this->content', '$this->datetime')";

And it works!
The only thing is that in the database and in the blog when i show it, there is only the day, month, and year. And not hour, minute and seconds.

Maybe it is because i set up in the field the type date, that somehow exclude the hours?
I should apply another type?

Comment: There's three MySQL date types: `DATE`, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP`. You need to use `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` to get both the date and time.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is use a timestamp column in the table that stores comments.
This way you don't have to do anything in your insert statement (DB does it for you).
Then, when you want to get that date, you must parse the value but it depends on which DataBase are you using.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO posts (name, mail, content, datetime) VALUES ('$this->name', '$this->mail', '$this->content', " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s) . ")";
```

To read `timestamp()`, use this code

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))); // ---->2013-06-22

// echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');     ---->2013-06-22 18:03:23
```